# Whether to say « le fragment de comète brisé » or « le fragment de comète brisée »?

Tags: accord

> Le fragment de comète ***brisé*** s'est écrasé en pleine mer.
>
> Le fragment de comète ***brisée*** s'est écrasé en pleine mer.

I wonder if I should have the adjective « brisé {broken} » qualify the masculine noun « fragment » or the feminine noun « comète », logically thinking.

Comment: I would reject both sentences. An idiomatic one would be *Le fragment de comète s'est abîmé en pleine mer*. As there is a fragment, we already know the comet was more or less broken in parts so *brisé(e)* is redundant.

Comment: Le fragment étant déjà une partie brisée de la comète je ne vois pas comment appliquer l'adjectif brisé à autre chose que la comète. Mais je ne suis pas aussi catégorique que @jlliagre pour éliminer la deuxième phrase.

Comment: Je ressens que pour ajouter "brisée" il faut mettre l'article défini : "le fragment de la comète brisée". Sans l'article ça sonne surchargé.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *“fragment”* is a piece of something that was broken or split. Thus *“fragment”* implies *“brisé”*. You could just write *“Le fragment de la comète s'est écrasé en pleine mer”*.

However, it is pretty common to reinforce an idea with a pleonasm, so your sentence is still valid. Now, as to which to prefer… I actually believe both to be correct, just placing a subtle emphasis either:

- For the first one, on the fact that the fragment that plummets into the sea is the result of a breaking. I would translate that to *“the piece that broke away from the comet”*. Focus is on the fragment.
- For the second one, on the fact that the comet has be broken, and this is just one piece of it. I would translate that to *“the piece of the broken comet”*. Focus is on the comet.

First sentence would be read the wrong way by less attentive readers, so you might want to reword it like this: *“Le fragment brisé de la comète s'est écrasé en pleine mer”*. It also makes the pleonasm stronger as the two words are together.

Comment: Note that "broken away" (like "broken off") is phrasal verbs that doesn't really correspond to "break apart/briser" (compared to e.g. séparer, détacher), so I don't think we can get "broken/brisé" in for the fragment unless, as Laure and Jonathan write, the fragment is itself internally breaking apart. On the contrary, I'm tempted to read that it's a whole fragment of a broken comet. :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak> You can find similar examples in litterature, for instance *“les fragments brisés de la carcasse d’un soldat”* — Mémoires d'Outre-Tombe, Chateaubriand, or *“les vers que j’ai publiés ne sont que des ébauches mutilées, des fragments brisés de ce poëme de mon âme”* — Des Destinées, Lamartine.

Comment: Hmm, okay. (Still not sure about a single fragment brisé, but I'd buy it based on that, especially the indefinite second one which couldn't be synecdoche.)

Comment: 'fragment brisé' is not a pleonasm! the conflict is between 'brisé' with the verb 's'écraser'. I also edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Merci. The omission of the definite article "the" was bothering me, too. I wonder if the speaker considered it to be a proper noun like "Comète SL9", the one and only comet in question? But even in this case, the letter "C" should be in uppercase, I suppose?

Comment: No uppercase "C" here. *Comète* is very unlikely to be used as a proper noun in French just like we do not say *Voyage vers Planète Mars*. We say *la comète SL9* or *la planète Mars*. The lack of article in *le fragment de comète* means it is a fragment from some unspecified comet, not a known comet which would lead to *le fragment de la comète*.

Answer (score 2):

The bigger mistake in this sentence is the improper use of the article. We would say either:

> un fragment de comète **brisé** s'est écrasé en pleine mer.
>
> Le/un fragment **de la** comète **brisée** s'est écrasé en pleine mer.
>
> Le/un fragment **d’une** comète **brisée** s'est écrasé en pleine mer.

Let’s note the ‘fragment brisé’ is quite confusing, because it can not 's'écraser' as it is already crushed. this is why I propose another example :

> **un morceau de** saucisse **séché** ne tente personne.
>
> Le/un morceau **de la** saucisse **séchée** ne tente personne

The article helps to determine if you consider the partition with ‘un morceau de’ or the main object with ‘de la’

This apply to all partitions: 'un fragment de’ ‘un peu de’ 'un morceau de’, …

**Additional,** I took this example because this is also correct:

> un morceau de saucisse sèche ne tente personne.
>
> un morceau de saucisse sec ne tente personne

But it is because 'saucisse sèche' is also a generic name :)

**Edit**: opinion over ‘fragment brisé’ conflict with 's'écraser'

Answer (score 1):

Depends I guess on whether it's to the fragment or the comet that you want to attribute the sense or "broken".

Here is where I got my answer for this:

http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-employe-sans-auxiliaire-177.php